# "At the last hour" vs. "in the last hour" in context

Tags: prepositions, difference

Can you please tell me if I need to use *at the last hour* or *in the last hour* in context below?

> The appointment was set up for 1-3pm and the customer showed up **at the last hour**.
>
> The appointment was set up for 1-3pm and the customer showed up **in the last hour**.

I'm trying to say that the customer showed when it was close to 3pm.

Are both possible and natural? If so, is there a difference in meaning?

Comment: There is the phrase **at the last minute** which is not usually taken literally, but means with little time to spare, nearly at 3pm in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct phrase is "**in** the last hour". It would mean the customer showed up between 2:00 and 2:59.

"**At** the last X-unit-of-time" is an idiomatic phrase similar to "at the last possible moment" that means "very close to the end of something", and not literally in the last hour, for instance.